# Does Vue have bilateral bind?

Tags: vue.js

```
<p contenteditable="true" v-bind="message"></p>
```

Object `@message` does not change when I edit the HTML element. Is there any simple way to do this using Vue.js?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, `contenteditable` doesn't work with `Vue` bindings such as `v-model`, it's recommended that you use a library such as [medium.js](http://jakiestfu.github.io/Medium.js/docs/) to build your own component.

However, if you're just trying to do something simple and keep the data in sync you can probably do that yourself:

**View Model**

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  methods: {
    updateMessage() {
        this.message = this.$refs.message.innerText;
    }
  },
  watch: {
    message() {
      this.$refs.message.innerText = this.message;
    }
  },
  data: {
    message: 'Hello'
  }
})
```

**HTML**

```
  <p ref="message" contenteditable="true" @keyup="updateMessage" class="editable">{{message}}</p>
```

As you can see you have to deal with updating the DOM yourself when using `contenteditable`. What I'm actually doing here is using a [ref](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#ref) to target the contenteditable, so I can get the inner text via `this.$refs.message.innerText`. I've then added a `@keyup` event which calls the `updateMessage` method to update the `message` data property. I've then added a `watcher` which reverses this process, so when message is updated it updates the contenteditable.

Here's the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/3ngc9486/

Answer (score 0):

Yes it has a two-way binding directive `v-model`, but it works only with input elements. So, instead of using a `p` element and handling that with complex JS, use a `textarea` with `v-model` and it will work out of the box.

```
<textarea v-model="message"></textarea>
```

here is an [example](https://jsfiddle.net/3ngc9486/1/).